# Why does changing the margin on :hover cause all occurrences to change?

Tags: html, css

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="cta">
     <div class="cta"></div>
     <div class="cta"></div>
     <div class="cta"></div>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
.cta {
     margin-bottom: -50px;
     transition: margin-bottom .2s;
}
.cta:hover {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

And whenever I hover over one of the 3 cta elements, all of their margin-bottoms get set to 0. Why is this? I only want one .cta element to be affected.

Comment: Your css is correct. I suspect a typo in your code, or maybe the way you arrange those elements made your mouse hover on all elements at the same time.

Comment: Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/h0au7tfm/) with your code - what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to apply the `hover` effect to `<div id="cta">`, then Change the code like this and then your hover affect will be applied to the main div

```
.cta {
 margin-bottom: -50px;
 transition: margin-bottom .2s;
}
#cta:hover {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: But I only want 1 .cta element to be affected, not all 3, which is the problem I'm having with this setup.

Comment: Can you share your HTML divs with content inside ... it would be better idd you post your jsfiddle.net link

Answer (score -1):

I don't meet your problem, and here's my demo for your question, can you see that? http://jsfiddle.net/abruzzi/1ns7ru0g/

```
#cta {
    margin: 100px;
}
.cta {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    transition: margin-bottom .2s;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.cta:hover {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
}


// below code for debug
.cta:nth-of-type(0) {
    background-color: red;
}
.cta:nth-of-type(1) {
    background-color: green;
}
.cta:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: "The rule `.cta:hover` will effect on all of tags that has a class `.cta`". This is completely incorrect. The hover effect will *not* expand to all elements with the class if a single instance was hovered on.

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to remove that incorrect statement?

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks for your suggestion, I am newbie in stackoverflow.

Comment: Newbie or not, you can still hit the delete button. I do not see why your incorrect/"unable to reproduce the problem" answer got two votes.

Answer (score -2):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="cta">
     <div class="cta" id="ctahov"></div>
     <div class="cta"></div>
     <div class="cta"></div>
</div>
```

and your CSS to this:

```
.cta {
 margin-bottom: -50px;
}
#ctahov {
 transition: margin-bottom .2s;
}
#ctahov:hover {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

This way, only the div with the `id="ctahov"` will have the desired `hover` effect.

Comment: Read the question again, not the other answers.